# Is using a Time-Series DB good for this case?

Tags: database-design, time-series, influxdb

Currently, I am using a timeseries databse to store sales across different stores. I have a measurement called `sales` where I have a `store_id` tag and the field `count` set to `1`. I am using InfluxDB's downsampling feature to sum up all the `count` fields so that I only have one single count per day. That's working great.

My issue here is, I need to be able to graph all my products on the X axis, and how much of each were sold on the Y axis, during a specific time range. I was thinking that `product_id` would be the tag and `count=1` would be the field. This way I can graph all the products sold on a set timeframe. However, I have hundreds of thousands of products, and I am not sure how Influx will react to this many series.

Should I be using something else to get the products sold on X amount of time, or is there a better way to measure this with influx, or am I doing it right?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple variables that come into play here.

1. What kind of hardware you're running InfluxDB on.
2. The number of stores that you have.
3. What kinds of queries you'll be running against your instance.
4. The version of InfluxDB that you're using.
5. What kind of read/write load you have on your instance.

In my experience, an `1.1` InfluxDB instance can handle about 2-5 million series on a single instance with 16G of RAM with light read/write load (assuming that you're not doing something like `GROUP BY product_id`).

So the number of stores that you have largely dictates the feasibility of this kind of schema. ~10 stores should probably be okay. ~100 probably not.

That being said, this schema should be perfectly fine in versions `1.2+` of InfluxDB as [support for high cardinality tags and series is being added](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/issues/7151).

Comment: If you can't group by a product id then how would you go about knowing how many sales X product had only?

Comment: You could do  `SELECT count(count) FROM sales where product_id = 'X'`, but `SELECT count(count) FROM sales GROUP BY product_id` would be problematic simply because you're asking for millions of points to come back at once.